# Kendo UI grid for AngularJS detail row automatically collapse after inserting itmes into detail data source

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI grid for AngularJS. The scenario is; I have expanded one master row which contains another grid in its detail template. When I insert new item in the detail template grid, the master row automatically collapsed. what I want is when I making changes to detail template grid than there must be no affect on master row(I mean should not be collapsed). any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might need to create a jsFiddle or a Plunk to explain the problem more succintly.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a dataBinding function to the grid to cancel the default action on the item Change event.

**Example Below:**

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        navigatable: true,
        sortable: true,
        dataBinding: function (e) {
            if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but I have faced the same scenario and come up with this, when you rebind/refresh grid by any mean, the grid get re rendered and thus you got collapse your row. apparently this behavior is of kendo ui. the only thing you can do is take that expanded row id and then rebind grid, after rebind expand that row again